# How do you store new value in a variable with an existing value based on a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am making a map using leaflet where on click, the values stored in the geojson properties populate textareas in a sidebar. I will use these values to construct an URL that will hit an API. My intention is that the user can click any three box where class = "selected" and get back info on the map based his or her selection. But I am unable to clear the previous variable that was stored in groupSelected with the new one clicked.

```js
//This grabs the geojson values and stores into the textarea tags in the sidebar

function checkInfo(e) {
 var properties = e.target.feature.properties;
 $("#nabe-name").html(properties.Name)
 $("#top-group").html(properties.largest)
 $("#second-group").html(properties.second)
 $("#third-group").html(properties.third)
};
//This is where I am stuck:
    $(".selected").on("click" ,function(e) {
 nabe = $("#nabe-name").val();
 var groupSelected= $(".selected").val();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="nabe-name">Neighborhood</textarea>
<textarea  class ="selected" id="top-group">Top</textarea>
<textarea class ="selected" id="second-group">Second</textarea>   
<textarea class ="selected" id="third-group">Third</textarea>
```

I need groupSelected variable to change everytime I click into a different textarea. I have to consider how I close my functions since I need the two variables available to the AJAX request.

Please help. If not obvious, I am new to JS. 
Thx

Comment: What if you do var groupSelected = e.target.value or $(this).val() ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the groupSelected variable to be set to?

Comment: What Yasin said...change `var groupSelected= $(".selected").val()` to `var groupSelected= $(this).val()`. You also might want to change the scope of the groupSelected variable if you want to use it outside the onclick function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always getting the value of the first `.selected` element. Access the clicked element with `this` keyword from inside the click `event handler.`

```
var groupSelected= $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `groupSelected` should be a global variable to hold the previous value and will be changed for the next click .I mean instead of creating in the click as `var groupSelected` it should be out side of the click listener